Create a Dashboard for ROS2 application
Where can I find a tutorial / documentation focused on creating a graphic dashboard (with QT) for ROS2 application?
For my scenario, it need to have some buttons for human interface with the robot states.

I think the QML ROS 2 plugin can be used for this.
Its license was changed to a permissive license in the meantime.
